# model.fit_generator : Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (args_2:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, data-fitting

I an using tenserflow to build a model

```
inputs1 = Input(shape=(2048,))
fe1 = Dropout(0.5)(inputs1)
fe2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fe1)
inputs2 = Input(shape=(max_length,))
se1 = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)
se2 = Dropout(0.5)(se1)
se3 = LSTM(256)(se2)

decoder1 =tf.keras.layers.Add()([fe2, se3])
decoder2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(decoder1)
outputs = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(decoder2)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
```

Then I am compiling it

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

then I am using the fit

```
for i in range(epochs):
    generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, wordtoix, max_length, number_pics_per_bath)
    model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
```

The error that I get is :

```
C:\...../Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py:513 <listcomp>
    data = [np.asarray(d) for d in data]
C:\.....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py:83 asarray
    
C:\....\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:728 __array__
    " array.".format(self.name))

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (args_2:0) to a numpy array.
```

I do not understand where the issue is . I went to the directory where the error occurred and change the np.asarray(d) for d in data to K.asarray(d) for d in data as I saw in some solution related to incompatibility between Keras and numpy. I also tried upgrading then downgrading these 2 Libs. It did not work!
Can some please help me in this?

Comment: Describe for us the nature of a `symbolic Tensor`.  That sounds 'virtual', 'symbolic', not fully there.  An array has to have real numbers.

Comment: This issue likely to be because of Numpy version compatibility or Python version. Tensorflow does not support Python 3.9. Make sure python >3.9 is installed. Thanks!